# Subscript and Superscript a String in Android

Tags: java, android, string, superscript, subscript

How can you print a string with a subscript or superscript? Can you do this without an external library? I want this to display in a `TextView` in Android.

Comment: use [this][1] trick in listview and its textview.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22105902/1350021

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>"));
```

or

[Common Tasks and How to Do Them in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext)

Comment: It technically isn't supporting HTML, that is creating a Spanned, which TextViews do support. Essentially CharSequences with style information.

Comment: This doesn't work for me...but maybe its cause I set it inside my strings.xml file.  It subscripts it for me but it clips it and no matter how much padding I put its always clipped.

Comment: Isn't parsing this html insanely expensive?

Comment: Link in answer doesn't seem relevant anymore.

Comment: Thanks for this but the answer below using a SpannableStringBuilder is much better.

Comment: `fromHtml(String)` was deprecated in Android N. [Use `fromHtml(String, int)` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37905107/5318303).

Comment: According to Mir-Imaili, you can call the same function with Html.fromHtml(String, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)

Answer (score 114):

Example:

```
equation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
SpannableStringBuilder cs = new SpannableStringBuilder("X3 + X2");
cs.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
cs.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
cs.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 6, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
cs.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f), 6, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
equation.setText(cs);
```

Comment: This actually looks right, thanks for sharing! The Html.fromHTML() method is convenient, but the superscript isn't smaller.

Comment: This is way better! The Html.fromHtml method can lead to the superscript text being cut off.

Comment: When I use this method like to say 100 meter square by `equation.setText(blah+cs);` it doesn't work. Works fine separately though. How to get that work?

Comment: Far better than **Html.fromHtml()** method

Comment: Please add explanation

Answer (score 54):

To all people asking, if you want to make it smaller besides of making super or subscript, you just need to add  tag as well. EX:

```
"X <sup><small> 2 </small></sup>"
```

Answer (score 23):

In the code just put this "\u00B2" Like this:

`textView.setText("X\u00B2");`

Comment: Hi,your answer was very helpful. However, what code can be used for subscript ? Also what are these codes called if i what to google them, are they unicodes ?

Comment: Hi, yes is unicode, here a PDF whit all unicodes https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf

Answer (score 15):

It bit late but following just work fine, use superscript as special character, I used spacial char here.

```
<string name="str">H₂</string>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup><small>2</small></sup>"));
```

(or) From String Resource File:

```
<string name="test_string">
  <![CDATA[ X<sup><small>2</small></sup> ]]>
</string>
```

Comment: i am new to stack over flow ,at that time dnt know how to use.

Answer (score 13):

The Accepted answer is deprecated now. So please go through this piece of code. I got this from some website. I forgot the name but anyway thanks for this good piece of working code.

```
     SpannableString styledString
            = new SpannableString("Large\n\n"     // index 0 - 5
            + "Bold\n\n"          // index 7 - 11
            + "Underlined\n\n"    // index 13 - 23
            + "Italic\n\n"        // index 25 - 31
            + "Strikethrough\n\n" // index 33 - 46
            + "Colored\n\n"       // index 48 - 55
            + "Highlighted\n\n"   // index 57 - 68
            + "K Superscript\n\n" // "Superscript" index 72 - 83 
            + "K Subscript\n\n"   // "Subscript" index 87 - 96
            + "Url\n\n"           //  index 98 - 101
            + "Clickable\n\n");   // index 103 - 112

    // make the text twice as large
    styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 5, 0);

    // make text bold
    styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 7, 11, 0);

    // underline text
    styledString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 13, 23, 0);

    // make text italic
    styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 25, 31, 0);

    styledString.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 33, 46, 0);

    // change text color
    styledString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 48, 55, 0);

    // highlight text
    styledString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), 57, 68, 0);

    // superscript
    styledString.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 72, 83, 0);
    // make the superscript text smaller
    styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), 72, 83, 0);

    // subscript
    styledString.setSpan(new SubscriptSpan(), 87, 96, 0);
    // make the subscript text smaller
    styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), 87, 96, 0);

    // url
    styledString.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.google.com"), 98, 101, 0);

    // clickable text
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            // We display a Toast. You could do anything you want here.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };

    styledString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 103, 112, 0);


    // Give the styled string to a TextView
    spantext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spantext);


    // this step is mandated for the url and clickable styles.
    spantext.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    // make it neat
    spantext.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    spantext.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    spantext.setText(styledString);
```

**Note :** Always put `android:textAllCaps="false"` of your spantext.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to set the superscript from string.xml file try this:

**string resource:**

```
<string name="test_string">X&lt;sup&gt;3&lt;/sup&gt;</string>
```

**if you want the superscript to be smaller:**

```
<string name="test_string">X&lt;sup&gt;&lt;small&gt;3&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/sup&gt;</string>
```

**Code:**

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Anything you want to put here"+getString(R.string.test_string)));
```

Answer (score 6):

## Android String Resource Superscript and Subscript for letters

#### You don't really have to use html document if any of the letters you want is represented here

For "a" copy and paste this "ᵃ"

You can copy and paste any of these Superscripts and Subscripts directly into your Android String Resource.

Example:

```
    <string name="word_with_superscript" translatable="false">Trademark ᵀᴹ</string>
```

Result:Trademark ᵀᴹ

**Superscript and Subscript letters**

***Superscript capital***   ᴬ   ᴮ       ᴰ   ᴱ       ᴳ   ᴴ   ᴵ   ᴶ   ᴷ   ᴸ   ᴹ   ᴺ   ᴼ   ᴾ       ᴿ       ᵀ   ᵁ   ⱽ   ᵂ

***Superscript minuscule*** ᵃ   ᵇ   ᶜ   ᵈ   ᵉ   ᶠ   ᵍ   ʰ   ⁱ   ʲ   ᵏ   ˡ   ᵐ   ⁿ   ᵒ   ᵖ       ʳ   ˢ   ᵗ   ᵘ   ᵛ   ʷ   ˣ   ʸ   ᶻ

***Subscript minuscule***   ₐ               ₑ           ₕ   ᵢ   ⱼ   ₖ   ₗ   ₘ   ₙ   ₒ   ₚ       ᵣ   ₛ   ₜ   ᵤ   ᵥ       ₓ

Answer (score 5):

The HTML.fromHTML(String) was deprecated as of API 24. They say to use this one instead, which supports flags as a parameter. So to go off of the accepted answer:

```
TextView textView = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text));
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

And if you want code that considers pre-24 API's as well:

```
TextView textView = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text));
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
  textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>"));    
}
```

This answer was derived from: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905107/4998704

The flags and other documentation can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Answer (score 3):

I found [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html) article on how to use a `Spannable` or in a string resource file: `<sup>` or `<sub>` for superscript and subscript, respectively.

Comment: Link in answer doesn't seem relevant anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Gerardo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48794436/969016) I created this extension on Int

```
fun Int.toSuperScript(): String {
    return when (this) {
        0 -> "\u2070"
        1 -> "\u00B9"
        2 -> "\u00B2"
        3 -> "\u00B3"
        4 -> "\u2074"
        5 -> "\u2075"
        6 -> "\u2076"
        7 -> "\u2077"
        8 -> "\u2078"
        9 -> "\u2079"
        else -> ""
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the `strings.xml` files, you can just use the HTML `<sup>3</sup>` tag. Work perfectly for me

**EXAMPLE**

```
<string name="turnoverRate">Turnover rate m<sup>3</sup>/m<sup>2</sup>/hour:</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are called Unicode characters, and Android `TextView` supports them. Copy the super/sub-script you want from this Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Superscripts_and_Subscripts

Answer (score -1):

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>"));

This will be the result in you yourTextView =
```

X<sup>2</sup>