# TextView Superscript not showing correctly

Tags: android, textview, superscript

I'm using the code found: [Subscript and Superscript a String in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android/3543625#3543625) in the first answer, but concatenating that from a previous string, so my code looks similar to:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(text.getText().toString()+Html.fromHtml("<sup>-2</sup>"));
```

Say, the contents of text was "3x", after setting the text using setText, it formats to "3x-2" with no subscript.

The XML for the TextView is:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
            android:text="3x"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="14pt"
            android:visibility="VISIBLE" 
/>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of this line..

```
text.setText(text.getText().toString()+Html.fromHtml("<sup>-2</sup>"));
```

try like this

```
 text.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.getText().toString()+"<sup>-2</sup>"));
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The same idea popped into my head just as I was checking Stackoverflow again for replies.

Comment: can i write like this:   text.setText("<sup>-2</sup>"+Html.fromHtml(text.getText().toString()));

Comment: i want textview like this *textviewText   while textview text is setting dynamically and i want to put * first as sup script and then textview text

Answer (score 4):

Please check the below its working fine for me

```
"TEXT<sup><small>TM</small></sup> TEXT"
```

The above code will make the TM to  Subscript and also make the text size small

Comment: Yes, tag <small> works fine! Thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Also for small size you can use-

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.getText().toString()+"<sup><small>-2</small></sup>"));
```

Put your whole text into only one `Html.fromHtml("Your whole string")`

From strings.xml

```
<string name="superscript_str">YourString&lt;sup&gt;&lt;small&gt;SuperScriptString&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/sup&gt;</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want display small as super text use

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.getText().toString()+"<sup>small>-2</small>/sup>"));
```