# How to add superscript text in android:label?

Tags: android, android-manifest

is there any way to add superscript text in android:label under Application tag?
I need to display name like :
    My<sup>android</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Refer this link

[Subscript and Superscript a String in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android)

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try using [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) as:

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.texta);
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("My<sup>android</sup>"));
```