# Unable to create superscript for Android Button text with Html.fromHtml()

Tags: android, android-layout, formatting

I've read through both of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156032/android-string-resource-superscript/22105902#22105902) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257315/how-to-add-superscript-text-in-androidlabel), which seem to have the same problem i'm struggling with, namely I have text for my buttons that i'd like to display as a superscript. In my fragment class in the `onCreateView` method I have added

```
if (rootView.findViewById(R.id.squared) != null) {
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.squared)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X <sup><small> 2 </small></sup>"));
                rootView.findViewById(R.id.squared).setOnClickListener(this);
            }
if (rootView.findViewById(R.id.cubed) != null) {
                    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cubed)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X <sup><small> 3 </small></sup>"));
                    rootView.findViewById(R.id.cubed).setOnClickListener(this);
```

In my `fragment_main` the buttons are coded as

```
<Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            android:id="@+id/squared"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

 <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:fontFamily="helvetica"
            android:id="@+id/cubed"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
```

However, when I run my application the layout doesn't any superscripted text.

[image]

Even when I change the text size from `15sp` to `10sp`, the text only gets smaller, but not superscripted. What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: Use "X<sup>2</sup>". `<sup/>` also narrows the text, no need to add `<small/>`.

Comment: or have a look at https://github.com/quiqueqs/BabushkaText

Comment: @DerGolem that still doesn't work

Comment: These are the tags supported by `Html.fromHtml`: https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd comment if I could, but at this point I can't.  I JUST posted something similar to this, an issue I'm having as well.  I had my problem solved halfway.  The method Html.fromHtml works for me only on a textview, but not on my butons.  I just wanted to say this in case it helps you or anyone else figure out how to employ this method on the buttons.  I'd very much like the answer myself.

Basically:
`textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("x<sup>2</sup"));` displays properly

BUT `button.setText(Html.fromHtml("x<sup>2</sup"));` displays x2 (without superscript).

EDIT:  AlanV helped me out.  Here's a link to the solution he provided someone else. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29056795/4535064

All you need to do is add this to your button:

```
<button
    android:textAllCaps="false";/>
```

The new version 5.0 (I think) forces buttons to produce all caps.  This is something I noticed when I produce the same string in a textview and button, and the button was all caps whereas the textview was not.  Because of this, you don't see the HTML formatting such as  and .  Setting the textAllCaps feature to "false" allows the HTML to be utilized.

Again, giving credit where it's due, AlanV is the man! :-)

Comment: @idclark I'm editing my post to actually include an answer now.  I received help for my issue and I believe you can benefit from it too.

Comment: that fixed it. Really appreciate you following up on this.

Comment: Heck yeah, awesome.  Just passing along what a few others sent my way.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, as shown [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67509).

I think the best thing to do is to set **android:textAllCaps="false"** , and then to set the text to be capitalized by yourself.