# Setting superscript text for android button

Tags: android, android-studio, button, superscript

I can't figure out how to set superscript text (for mathematical operators) in an android button.

As the code below suggests, I want `buttonXPow` to display:

X<sup>y</sup>

And I want `button10Pow` to display:

10<sup>y</sup>

I want to avoid having to resort to displaying `X^y` and `10^y` where possible.

---

The only possible solution I've found so far is this code ([found in this stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199360/unable-to-create-superscript-for-android-button-text-with-html-fromhtml)):

```
protected void onCreateView() {

    if (rootView.findViewId(R.id.buttonXPow) !=null) {
        ((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonXPow)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X <sup><small> y </small></sup>"));
    }
    if (rootView.findViewId(R.id.button10Pow) !=null) {
        ((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button10Pow)).setText(Html.fromHtml("10 <sup><small> y </small></sup>"));
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that `rootView` cannot be resolved. I'm not sure how I can get that working (obviously it's not a class I need to import; I'm assuming I need to declare a variable somehow).

Is there any other known way of setting superscript text; perhaps with xml rather than in the main java class?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android
it has answers to declare text in xml file

Comment: Yep that works, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following to the onCreate method works

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.buttonXPow)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>y</sup>"));
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.button10Pow)).setText(Html.fromHtml("10<sup>y</sup>"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your strings.xml file add the following-

`<string name="test_string">
  <![CDATA[ X<sup><small>2</small></sup> ]]>
</string>`

and then in your activity access it with-

`getResources().getString(R.string.test_string)`

this will work to get x^2

Comment: The issue is not that the `setText(Html.fromHtml("X <sup><small> y </small></sup>"));` doesn't work, it's that `rootView` can't be resolved so the code doesn't even get that far.