# Display Service Mark in Android Screen

Tags: android

It seems as though the [Service Mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2120/index.htm) UTF code is not supported by Android.  I have the below in my strings.xml file and I only get an empty box.  The copyright works fine. Any ideas?

```
<string name="test">Test\u2120</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use a custom font which has Service Mark. Or perhaps easier would be to [use superscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android).