# Superscript layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, superscript

I am on making a widget layout, I need to display `superscript` type thing like [image: this], like `PM` displaying in this picture, I am thinking if there is any tool which acts like superscript. Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [Html#fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) and use the [HTML < sup > tag](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlsuperscript.php).
Here is what it will look like if you set the text in a `TextView` in java:

```
textView.setText("3:36" + Html.fromHtml("<sup>PM</sup>"));
```

More info can be found on this SO Post: [Subscript and Superscript a String in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android)

Comment: I tried this its not making superscript, is it because of small text size ?