# How to display mathematical power values in xml

Tags: android, xml

I have a xml which I am parsing and displaying the values.

```
<question>
    The frequency of tuning fork is 1000 Hz and velocity of sound in air 300 ms-1.The distance travelled by sound while the fork executes 500 oscillations is
</question>
```

In this as you can see 300 ms to the power -1 is the exact value. But while parsing it is not displayed.

Also I need to display `10^8 as (10 to the power 8 )`

How to display these values. Itried including ASCII code but it does not work.

Please help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android

Comment: Hey anu! Welcome to SO. You have come up with a nice idea. But you will have to take a step and work to implement it. Share with us some code what you have written or at what point you failed to achieve it. Everyone is here to help. This is not a place to ask for readymade codes without showing us some effort you took to solve it.Happy Coding :)

Comment: @PareshMayani We need to display it in a textview. I dont think it does not matter whether its a textview or edittext.

Comment: @Abhilasha i have implemented DOM parser to parser the xml.

Comment: @MarcinK we can do this but what my prob is i dont have 1 question i have 10 questions which i am parsing dynamically using for loop...