# How to refresh a view every few seconds in android?

Tags: android

In my app I am transfering pictures in a background service. For each picture I have database entry in my sqlite db. Now I want to add a info area on my main screen which shows the amount of pictures which needs to be transfered. This area should refresh every 10 seconds, so that a user can see if how many jobs need to be done.

What is the best practice in android to solve such a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can try to create a 'recursive call' of the method with a delay of 10 seconds

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    //do anything


    }
    }, 10000);
```

** or better use this below method

```
Timer t = new Timer();

void timerMethod()
{
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
public void run() {


Log.d("timer", "timer ");
//do anything


}
}, 10000, 10000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually updating every 10 seconds, it might be better to have it update every time a task completes.  As long as the task isn't occurring on the UI thread, the two won't interfere with eachother. It'll also make the app feel much smoother if a progress bar gradually fills (or a percentage number gradually rises, or whatever) as opposed to one massive change every 10 seconds.

In order to update the UI from a non UI thread, you need to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).  There's a good example of how to use a Handler to communicate from a service to the UI on Android's [developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html).

Comment: yeah this sounds as a good way, how can i inform/update my view that the service finished a task? Do you have an example? Thanks

Comment: Updated response to include relevant links-  Basically, you use the Handler object.  You can put code in there that will execute on the Activity's UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AsyncTask`. Work goes in `doInBackground()`, update the UI during the task with `publishProgress()`, update the UI at the end of the task with `onPostExecute()`. The advantage to `AsyncTask` is that it handles creating and managing the `Handler`s for you and provides a concise location to build your code.

See my comment here for skeleton code: [preventing app from looking hung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842316/preventing-app-from-looking-hung/13844089#13844089)

Also read over the API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

And a tutorial on AsyncTasks: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask