# Superscript/subscript in ListView (android)

Tags: android, html, listview, superscript

I'm new to android and I'm just learning.
I want some help on how to get superscript in ListView in android.
For now, I have a TextView which can make it by < sup > tag using Html.fromHtml() function to get e.g. 2<sup>3</sup>.
But now I have just start learning to use ListView and don't know exactly how to use it, but < sup > tag doesn't work.

In onCreate I have this:

```
...
// Create and populate a history list
String[] history = new String[] {};
ArrayList<String> historyList = new ArrayList<String>();
historyList.addAll(Arrays.asList(history));

// Create ArrayAdapter using the history list.
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.history_list, historyList);
// Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
historyListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

And in onClick/AsyncTask/onPostExecute I have this:

```
...
listAdapter.add(outputToHistory);
```

In history_list.xml I have this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" >
</TextView>
```

Thanks

Comment: use [this][1] trick to use html tag from string resource


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22105902/1350021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3543625/72746) for a related question,
the  tag should work:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>"));
```

Comment: This works with TextView, but how can I handle it within ListView?

Comment: exactly the same way - when you are filling your ListView items in your adapter, call setText like in the example. You might have to create a custom adapter for this, or maybe use ArrayAdapter<Spannable>, and supply array of Spannables created with Html.fromHtml("...")