# Android String Resource Superscript

Tags: java, android, string, subscript, superscript

I have a string resource file, which I want to pull strings from and I want one of the strings to have some superscript in it.

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html it looks like the supported tags include `<b>`, `<i>`, and `<u>`. I'm curious if it should work for other related tags, such as `<sup>`... if so then my problem is solved.

Testing the above should be easy enough, I'm just looking for a deeper understanding, to see if everything is processed similar to [Subscript and Superscript a String in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android) or if there is extra processing that happens when pulling the strings from the resource string file.

Comment: AFAIK, only `<b>`, `<i>`, and `<u>` are supported.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so there is extra processing or filtering that is done on string resource files?

Comment: I'd describe it as less processing. AFAIK, string resources aren't piped through `Html.fromHtml()`, but through a simpler parser that only looks for those tags. I seem to recall trying other tags without luck, though that would have been a while ago. My assumption is that it's a matter of performance, as `Html.fromHtml()` isn't the speediest thing going.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48493843/1820553

Answer (score 4):

You can use X\u00B2 to create X^2 in xml directly

Answer (score 1):

I am using this trick: In string resource:

```
<string name="text1">x!sup@2!/sup@</string>
```

Then in activity:

```
text1.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text1).replace("!", "<").replace("@", ">")));
```

this trick is working.

Comment: I tried but didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 1):

`<string name="sup_string"> a<sup><small>n</small></sup> b </string>`

a<sup>n</sup> b

this worked for me.

Comment: Tried this but didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

You can escape like this:

```
<string name="acceleration"><![CDATA[%1$f m.s<sup><small>-2</small></sup>]]></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Android String Resource Superscript and Subscript for letters

You can copy and paste any of these Superscripts and Subscripts directly into your Android String Resource.

Example:

```
    <string name="word_with_superscript" translatable="false">Trademark ᵀᴹ</string>
```

Result:Trademark ᵀᴹ

**Superscript and Subscript letters**

***Superscript capital***   ᴬ   ᴮ       ᴰ   ᴱ       ᴳ   ᴴ   ᴵ   ᴶ   ᴷ   ᴸ   ᴹ   ᴺ   ᴼ   ᴾ       ᴿ       ᵀ   ᵁ   ⱽ   ᵂ

***Superscript minuscule*** ᵃ   ᵇ   ᶜ   ᵈ   ᵉ   ᶠ   ᵍ   ʰ   ⁱ   ʲ   ᵏ   ˡ   ᵐ   ⁿ   ᵒ   ᵖ       ʳ   ˢ   ᵗ   ᵘ   ᵛ   ʷ   ˣ   ʸ   ᶻ

***Subscript minuscule***   ₐ               ₑ           ₕ   ᵢ   ⱼ   ₖ   ₗ   ₘ   ₙ   ₒ   ₚ       ᵣ   ₛ   ₜ   ᵤ   ᵥ       ₓ