# How to display upright textview?

Tags: android, html, textview, currency

I want to display a little currency unit "đ" like [this link](http://prntscr.com/8omsly) in TextView. 
My code:

```
<string name="dong" formatted="false"><![CDATA[<u><small><font color="#FA6D1D">đ</font></small></u>]]></string>
```

But the little "đ" is not at the upright. So how can i do?
Any comment is preciated. Thank in advance.

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Comment: look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira: Thank you, i found my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
setText(Html.fromHtml("15.000.000<sup><small>đ</small></sup>"));
```

For more details you can visit here

> [Android String Resource Superscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156032/android-string-resource-superscript/22105902#22105902)

Comment: in here you can use `<font color=\"#FA6D1D\">"`

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
String yourValue = "15.000.000";
editText.setText(yourValue + Html.fromHtml("<u><sup><small><font color=red>d</font></small></sup><u/><br><br/>"));
```