# Displaying Superscript and Special symbols in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am using

```
private final static String MICRO = "&amp;#x3BC";
```

and

```
private final static String SQUARE = "&amp;#xB2";
```

to display ms^2 and MICRO symbol as

```
case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
    units = "m/s" + SQUARE;
case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
    units = MICRO + "T";
```

But its returning same values. i.e `MICRO = "&amp;#x3BC"; and SQUARE = "&amp;#xB2";` on App. Is there an alternative way to display these units?

Comment: I haven't tested this but each unicode should start with `&` and should end with `;` so lets take your first example. `&amp;#x3BC` this is two codes  - `&amp;` and `#x3BC` but second one doesn't follow the rules. Change MICRO to `&amp;&#x3BC;` and SQUARE to `&amp;&#xB2;`

Comment: I tried what you suggested changed `"&amp;#x3BC"` to `"&amp;#x3BC;"`.
Still no changes on app it displays as m/s&amp;#x3BC;  itself.

Comment: `"&amp;#x3BC;"` is wrong. you're still missing `&` before `#`. Try copy and paste this `"&amp;&#x3BC;"`

Comment: Now its displaying as ms&^2 and &microsecond

Comment: Can you show exactly what you are hoping to achieve? What is the final thing you want to see on the screen? Even if you can paste an image of the text from somewhere else. Just show the final result you are hoping to get

Comment: I am trying to create units of acceleration and Time similar to this [picture](https://imgur.com/a/srmVK)

Comment: Thank you @THEPATEL for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Changing `MICRO = "&amp;#x3BC"; to MICRO = "&#x3BC;";` and 
`SQUARE = "&amp;#xB2"; to SQUARE = "&#xB2;";` works

Answer (score 0):

Here's another options - use HTML.

First, create XML strings

```
<string name="ms"><![CDATA[%1$s m/s<sup><small><small>2</small></small><sup>]]></string>
<string name="ut"><![CDATA[%1$s &mu;T]]></string>
```

Now, use them in your Java:

```
TextView txtMs = findViewById(R.id.txtMs);
String ms2 = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.ms), "2.8");
txtMs.setText(Html.fromHtml(ms2));

TextView txtUt = findViewById(R.id.txtUt);
String ut = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.ut), "2000.0");
txtUt.setText(Html.fromHtml(ut));
```

Result:

[image]