# How to add format in Android Edit Text text

Tags: java, android

I'm making a calculator for Android.. and I'd like to see my expressions in a cool format..

**example**: instead of **2^2** I'd like to see **2²**.

The expression is shown in an Edit Text.

how can i achieve that? I've found nothing use full yet on the Internet.

thanks a lot!!

Comment: It seems you didn't look hard enough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Html.fromHtml()` where you could `setText()` like this `tv.setText("2<sup>2</sup>")`