# Change font of superscript text

Tags: android, html, font-size, superscript

I am writing an view where I need to display superscript data. I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3543625/2624806) to achieve this.

Along this is there any way to change font size(in number) of superscript text.

**EDIT**
Commanware suggested [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8872986/2624806) work great, except one thing. I need superscript bit above of base text. I'm updating image for same, please refer. I'm using same code with mention in reference code.

[image]

Here either can go for separate text view could be second priority solution. Any suggestion !

Comment: Try other answers from that question, such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8872986/115145

Comment: I checked with available tag <small> but I still need to make it look more small.

Comment: The answer that I linked to did not use `<small>`.

Comment: @CommonsWare with other type face it giving bit issue. Super Script not showing top side of text, it come bit parallel of text. Any suggestion how can avoid such situation.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you mean. I suggest that you open a separate Stack Overflow question, showing your current code, plus screenshots of what you are seeing that represents a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74633/discussion-between-shubh-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 3):

try this one this is working code:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("04:30<sup><small>pm</small></sup>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant pass text size in numbers, yo have to change the size to string :

```
<font size="3" color="red">This is some text!</font>
```

Comment: first increase you text size then convert it in script.

Answer (score -1):

Use this Code :

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("your Text <sup style="font-size:5(yourfontsize);">subscript</sup>"));
```

Try this and Let me know :)

Comment: I updated it bit...txtTime.setText(Html.fromHtml("your Text <sup style=\"font-size:5(" + yourfontsize + "); \">" + unit + " </sup>"));  but it's not reflecting anything new.

Comment: Increase  TextView  Font Size and Check setText(Html.fromHtml("your Text <sup style="font-size:5;">subscript</sup>"));

Comment: ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("your Text <sup style="font-size:0;">subscript</sup>")); Make it 0 and check whether it is working not

Comment: This is also not working, font size I'm using is 32sp for TextView. Checked with both above solution but not working. ;|