# how to superscript in a title in androidplot?

Tags: android, android-xml, androidplot

I'm trying to superscript a number in a title in androidplot, like so:

strings file:

```
<string name="plot_title_3m">stuff per m<sup>3</sup></string>
```

xml file:

```
androidPlot.title="@string/plot_title_3m"
```

but it doesn't superscript at all, the number is normal styling.  I've also tried using

```
<string name="plot_title_3m">stuff per m&lt;sup&gt;3&lt;/sup&gt;</string>
```

but no dice, it actually shows the sup tags in the title

also tried this

```
<string name="plot_title_3m">stuff per m<small><sup>3</sup></small></string>
```

and actually found out that the 'small' tags don't work either...

Comment: Looking at the source code for [androidPlot](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/397fac6a3541b4020a716e958a9c0b42bd2450fd/AndroidPlot-Core/src/main/java/com/androidplot/Plot.java?at=master#cl-831), I do not think this is possible without some modification of the source. To show superscript on a TextView, you need to pass in a `Spannable` to `TextView#setText(CharSequence)`, but androidPlot currently converts title text to a plain String.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTML tags to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android). To be more exact, you need to use [Spans](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html) on your input text to achieve this look on TextView, but we have [a friendly neighborhood helper class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) that converts some common HTML tags into spans.

E.g.:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>"));
```

Comment: I don't think that would work since the whole plot has an ID, but not the title...

Comment: Oh, you're right, I misinterpreted the problem. I agree with Ugo, you could try to modify the lib accordingly and somehow pass in a Spannable. OR maybe you could extract the title from the plotting View and show it in a separate TextView?