# Android Formatting Superscript and Subscript

Tags: android, textview, format, superscript, spanned

I have an array of Strings that I want to display within a proper format for my TextViews. I have already looked at using the Html.fromHtml() approach as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android) but I still can't figure out my specific solution.

The issue that I encounter is I am not sure how to format just a portion of the string. 
The "^" char should be a super script  and the "_" underscore should be a subscript. Anything within brackets "{}" means that the superscript/subscript should apply to everything within it.

For example: The string  **^2S_{1/2}** should be displayed as: **<sup>2</sup>S<sub><sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub></sub>**

Another example: **1s^2** should be formatted within a textview to appear as such: **1S<sup>2</sup>**

I have been stumped for the past couple hours. All help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example to format this ^2S_{1/2}, you will write your string value as

"<sup><small>2</small></sup> S <sub><small>½</small></sub>".

And write symbols in their codes and also use Html.fromHtml() in your TextView setText() method.

Comment: Thank you. I also discovered that if you try to concatenate a string with the Spanned object, it will not format.So do not concatenate such as the following:  myTextView.setText(myString + Html.fromHtml(sup><small>2</small></sup>));