# superscript <SUP> tag not working

Tags: android

`<string name="sqr">x<sup>2</sup></string>`

and

`((Button) findViewById(R.id.sqrBtn)).setText(Html.fromHtml("x<sup>2</sup>"));`

these both show:

[image: SUP tag not working]

but it works for TextView. just button have this problem (differs from [Subscript and Superscript a String in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android) thanks for understanding)

ON:

- SM-G920F Galaxy S6 -- Android 6.0.1 (STOCK) - API v23
- GT-I9100 Galaxy S2 -- Android 6.0.1 (CM13) - API v23

Additional info:

Tag:

```
<Button  style="@style/calcBtn"
         android:text="@string/sqr"
         android:id="@+id/sqrBtn" />
```

Style:

```
<style name="calcBtn">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">35sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#f2f2f2</item>
    <item name="android:background">#282828</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">12dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscript and Superscript a String in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android)

Comment: @buczek  that solution was for TextView but it doesn't work for Button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `android:textAllCaps="false"` on the `Button`. By default, on `Theme.Material` and `Theme.AppCompat`, you get all caps, which breaks any formatting you attempt to apply to the `Button` text.