# how to display scientific notation to power of 10 instead of "E" in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an Android calculator and I want to display large numbers in powers of 10 instead of "E" like this:

```
10²
```

Instead of:

```
E2
```

Can you guys help and thanks?

Comment: String replace ought to work.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android) may help you.
This uses html super script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String text="2";// is prefix to your upper text(2) and enclosed with 
yourtextview.settext(Html.fromHTML(text));