# Format amount string

Tags: android

Can anyone help me to achieve below amount string format in android application.

[image]

Comment: This probably requires a specialized font for the raised dollar sign and zeros.

Answer (score 7):

Android smartphones support writing any text in **subscript or superscript** .
You can try with

```
Html.fromHtml("<sup>$</sup>1,500<sup>00</sup>");
```

Without using **HTML** tag You can visit **[Subscript and Superscript a String in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android/8872986#8872986)**

Comment: @V.J. look here for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/8872986/3383038

Comment: @OlegOsipenko Good info .

Comment: IntelliJAmiya @OlegOsipenko Nice Tutorial.
There is a lot of ideas to achieve this type of string output.

Answer (score 1):

// For the superscript and subscript you can take help of html tag

```
    String yourText="$1,050<sup>00</sup>";
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourText,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY))
    } else {
        yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourText));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Copy past it inside your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dollar"
        android:text="$"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dollar"
        android:id="@+id/ammount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:text="1,050"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ammount"
        android:id="@+id/zeroes"
        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ohhh sorry. It is Good try but not work for me. As i have to change my layout too..