# Superscript in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I am a cse 3rd year student .I am working on OCR equation solver project of my course, I need to write superscript form in polynimial equatione.
I have already used this method

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup>"));
```

but it doen't work , I have failed to find out what is wrong,Or any better idea ? suggest please
.. help me .Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your target SDk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscript and Superscript a String in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android)

Comment: The accepted answer to the original question may not work for apps targeting N+ but there is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8872986/5015207) which should still work