# Android - go to superscript in textview on button click

Tags: android

I'm creating calculator on Android. I want to go to superscript in my textview (containing expression) when user clicks "**^**" button, so I can write in the upper index.

What I want to achieve is shown in the picture below:

[image]

How can I do this? Is there any library which could help me?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android

Comment: I have seen this before. But i mean something like moving cursor to superscript, so user can write in upper index in real time. Maybe is there any library that allows this?

Comment: What have you tried? Try searching on StackOverflow for older questions and google as well as github.