# How to show $ symbol on other text in textview

Tags: android

Hi i want to show some symbol above other text like $ and % how to achieve this.Following is reference image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SExAb.png)

I have one textview in that i directly added it as:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/month_txt"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:text="$0.99/Month"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
```

for bold font i reied like

```
month_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("$0.99" + "<b>" + "/Month" + "</b>"));
```

now bold font is working but not able to get $  sign above actual price

But as expected it show all in same lline. How to achieve this like above image

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android

Comment: That's called superscript. The linked duplicate has several different methods to achieve that, both programmatically, or in XML with resources.

Comment: Yeah, you're almost there. Just add `<sup>` tags to your example: `Html.fromHtml("<sup><small>$</small></sup>0.99" + "<b>" + "/Month" + "</b>")`. You can add `<small>` tags, too, if you want it a little shorter, as mentioned in one of the answers there.

Comment: ok using Html.fromHtml("X<sup>2</sup> i can achieve this now one question how i can change font size for this 2 its very large (same as X). I want to reduce its size as comapred to X

Comment: I was just editing my above comment. You can add `<small>` tags, too, as mentioned in [this answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16362479). You can do that multiple times, btw, to get it to your desired size.

Comment: Hi Mike Thank you so much for your time and answer. Good day ahead