# Superscript and Subscript on Button in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, button, superscript

I am making a Scientific Calculator in Android Studio. I need to write x^2 as **Superscipt** and etc like this in Button text. How to do it?

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnX2"
        android:text=
        >
    </Button>
```

Here in text what should I write?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subscript and Superscript a String in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android)

Comment: This is already answered here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543454/subscript-and-superscript-a-string-in-android